# Replace character depend on the data

Tags: php

```
$defaultdata = "abcdef00000000000000000000000000";

$data1 = "271";

$output = "abcdef00000000000000000000000271";
```

How can I replace the string based on the data. For example, if the default data is **abcdef00000000000000000000000000** , so it will replace when the data1 got value. So the output will be abcdef00000000000000000000000271. How can I do this?

Comment: In many ways, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use `substr`:

```
$output = substr($defaultdata,0,strlen($defaultdata)-strlen($data1)) . $data1;
```

### Applying it to your code

```
<?php
$defaultdata = "abcdef00000000000000000000000000";
$data1 = "271";
$output = substr($defaultdata,0,strlen($defaultdata)-strlen($data1)) . $data1;
echo $output;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $output = substr($defaultdata, 0, strlen($defaultdata) - strlen($data1));
$output .= $data1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to solve this is to use `str_pad`. It is a built in function made to tackle situations like yours. Then you can easly swap defaultdata to something other. The code is as follow:

```
$output = str_pad($data1, strlen($defaultdata), $defaultdata, STR_PAD_LEFT);
```